# Groovy list method with default parameters didn't match

Tags: grails, groovy

I implemented the follow list method for a POGO class

```
def list (def sort=null, def order=null, def max=null, def offset=null) {
..
}
```

When I call it from controller

```
render view: 'index', model: [orderList: Order.list(params.sort, params.order, params.max, params.offset), orderCount:orders.size()]
```

I got the folllowing error

```
    No signature of method: static mypackage.Order.list() is applicable for argument types: (null, null, null, null) values: [null, null, null, null]
    Possible solutions: list(), wait(), find(), list(java.lang.Object), list(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), list(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object). Stacktrace follows:
    Message: No signature of method: static latis.ctl.Job.list() is applicable for argument types: (null, null, null, null) values: [null, null, null, null]
    Possible solutions: list(), wait(), find(), list(java.lang.Object), list(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), list(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
        Line | Method
    ->>    6 | showInstances in latis.ctl.JobController
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    198 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
    |     63 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
    |     53 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
    |     49 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
    |     82 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
    |   1145 | runWorker . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    615 | run           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    744 | run . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
java.lang.Object), list(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: Clearly the method is not static and being called from the Class reference `Order.list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace and the controller code show you're calling a static method (calling the method on the class instead of on an instance). The method you show the definition for is an instance method. You're not calling the method that you defined.

You could define the method using `static def` if you intend for it to be a static method.